# Howto warm up a mysql database

Tags: mysql

I would like to know howto warm up a mysql database.

I have read you have to size your innodb_buffer_pool_size with following query:

```
SELECT CEILING(Total_InnoDB_Bytes*1.6/POWER(1024,3)) RIBPS FROM 
(SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) Total_InnoDB_Bytes
FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='InnoDB') A;`
```

Because my database is rather small, i use it without `ceiling` and i get sometime like 0,200.
So i altered my innodb_buffer_pool_size to 256MB. (I only have 1 GB ram).

I've read somewhere you can use following query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fiets FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY);`

But my `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_pages_%';` shows that only 4391 of 16383 are filled.

How do i warm my database at start up? Can someone give me a sql query?

@Juhana. I know my database is small, but i would like to get the best performance. (school project)

Comment: *"Because my database is rather small [..]"* -- are you sure warming up is really necessary?

Comment: If the database is very small, the warming up process will most likely cost much more than any benefit you'd get from it. (Please don't edit the question to reply to comments, use the comment system.)